# Replace a column in a csv file in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new in python and just learned how to use pandas. I have a csv file called Data.csv that has a value of A or B in the last column

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('filelocation/Data.csv', header = None)

last_col = data.iloc[0:208, 60]
print(last_col)
```

The last column looks like this:

```
A
B
B
A
A
```

I replaced every R and M using the following code:

```
last_col = data.iloc[0:208,60].replace(['R','M'],[0,1])
```

which results into:

```
0
1
1
0
0
```

My problem now is how to replace the column that contains R and M in the variable data with the 0 and 1 stored in last_col (and assign them as a new variable data_2)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: data ['last_col']=last_col

Comment: `data.iloc[:, -1] = last_col`. `-1` would give you last column.